# Fill a 2D array from user inputs as strings

Tags: c#, matrix, tic-tac-toe

I have to find the winner of a 3x3 TicTacToe game. Firstly I user input N (number of moves) and then N moves like: (1 0),(0 2) etc. where first int is the row index and second int the column index. (X starts the game,0 continue and so on). The program needs to return the winner "X" or "0", or return "Draw" if there is not a winner. For example for the following input:

- 7
- 1 1
- 2 1
- 2 0
- 0 2
- 1 0
- 1 2
- 0 0

The output is : X

I have the following code:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp20
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static string Tictactoe(int[][] moves)
        {
            int[] rowsValues = new int[3];
            int[] columnsValues = new int[3];
            int diagonalSum = 0;
            int antiDiagonalSum = 0;
            const int c1 = 3;
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            bool isFirstPlayer = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                int rowIndex = moves[i][0];
                int columnIndex = moves[i][1];
                int value = isFirstPlayer ? 1 : -1;

                if (rowIndex == columnIndex)
                {
                    diagonalSum += value;
                }

                if (columnIndex == c1 - rowIndex - 1)
                {
                    antiDiagonalSum += value;
                }

                rowsValues[rowIndex] += value;
                columnsValues[columnIndex] += value;
                if (Math.Abs(diagonalSum) == c1 ||
                   Math.Abs(antiDiagonalSum) == c1 ||
                   Math.Abs(rowsValues[rowIndex]) == c1 ||
                   Math.Abs(columnsValues[columnIndex]) == c1)
                {
                    return isFirstPlayer ? "X" : "0";
                }

                isFirstPlayer = !isFirstPlayer;
            }

            return "Draw";
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            ReadValues(Tictactoe);
        }

        static int[][] ReadValues()
        {
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int i = n; n > 0; n--)
            {
                string[] moves = Console.ReadLine().Split();
                int a = int.Parse(moves[0]);
                int b = int.Parse(moves[1]);

             // This method needs some adjustments

     static int[][] FillMatrix

            // This is the method that I need help at.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to create a 2D array in your `ReadValues` function with 2 columns and `n` rows (based on what the user enters as number of moves).

```
public static int[,] ReadValues() // I changed the return type
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[,] movesArr = new int[n,2];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // you need to adjust your index variable like so.
    {
        string[] moves = Console.ReadLine().Split();
        int a = int.Parse(moves[0]); // consider giving a and b more meaningful names
        int b = int.Parse(moves[1]); // 'a' and 'b' is very vague, bad practice
        movesArr[i,0] = a;
        movesArr[i,1] = b;
    }
    return movesArr;
}
```

Then in your `Main` function you need to do `TicTactoe(ReadValues());` instead of `ReadValues(Tictactoe);`.  `ReadValues` is returning a 2D `int` array which is used as the argument to the `Tictactoe` function. So you need to change the function definition for `Tictactoe` to this as well:
`public static string Tictactoe(int[,] moves)`

And in `Tictactoe`, the statements to get the row and column index need changed to

```
int rowIndex = moves[i,0];
int columnIndex = moves[i,1];
```

One last thing you need to do is delete the `Console.ReadLine()` in the `Tictactoe` function since that will just halt your program and you already got the number of moves from the user at the beginning of the `ReadValues` function.

I don't know what your `FillMatrix` function is supposed to be but you shouldn't need that. You have to fill the 2D array in that `for` loop within the `ReadValues` function.

Comment: declaring int [ , ] moves does not allow me using int[][] after. So which one should be used?

Comment: ah yes I forgot to change the return type of `ReadValues`. see my updates